# List out of range inside the function, but when done manually works

Tags: python, algorithm, minmax

```
leaf=[]
leaf.append([1,8])
leaf.append([5])
leaf.append([6,4,7])
leaf.append([9])
leaf.append([3,2])
leaf.append([6,10,2])
max=[]
min=[]
count=0

def childset_max(counter,*arg):
    global max
    if len(arg)==3:
        if arg[0] > arg[1]:
            if arg[0] > arg[2]:
                max.insert(counter,arg[0])
                leaf[counter]=[max[counter]]
            else:
                max.insert(counter,arg[2])
                leaf[counter]=[max[counter]]

        else:
            if arg[1] > arg[2]:
                max.insert(counter,arg[1])
                leaf[counter] = [max[counter]]
            else:
                max.insert(counter,arg[2])
                leaf[counter] = [max[counter]]
    elif len(arg)==2:
        if arg[0]>arg[1]:
            max.insert(counter,arg[0])
            leaf[counter] = [max[counter]]
        else:
            max.insert(counter,arg[1])
            leaf[counter] = [max[counter]]
    else:
        max.insert(counter,arg[0])
        leaf[counter] = [max[counter]]

    return max

def childset_min(counter,*arg):
    global min
    if len(arg)==3:
        if arg[0] < arg[1]:
            if arg[0] < arg[2]:
                min.insert(counter,arg[0])
                leaf[counter]=[min[counter]]
            else:
                min.insert(counter,arg[2])
                leaf[counter]=[min[counter]]

        else:
            if arg[1] < arg[2]:
                min.insert(counter,arg[1])
                leaf[counter] = [min[counter]]
            else:
                min.insert(counter,arg[2])
                leaf[counter] = [min[counter]]
    elif len(arg)==2:
        if arg[0]<arg[1]:
            min.insert(counter,arg[0])
            leaf[counter] = [min[counter]]
        else:
            min.insert(counter,arg[1])
            leaf[counter] = [min[counter]]
    else:
        min.insert(counter,arg[0])
        leaf[counter] = [min[counter]]

    return min

def min_move():
    count=0
    while (count<6):
        if len(leaf[count])==6:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count]                [2],leaf[count][3],leaf[count][4],leaf[count][5])
        elif len(leaf[count])==5:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count]    [2],leaf[count][3],leaf[count][4])
        elif len(leaf[count])==4:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count]    [2],leaf[count][3])
        elif len(leaf[count])==3:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0],leaf[count][1],leaf[count][2])
        elif len(leaf[count])==2:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0],leaf[count][1])
        elif len(leaf[count])==1:
            childset_min(count, leaf[count][0])
        count=count+1
    return min

def max_move():
    count=0
    while (count<6):
        if len(leaf[count])==6:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count]    [2],leaf[count][3],leaf[count][4],leaf[count][5])
        elif len(leaf[count])==5:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count][2],leaf[count][3],leaf[count][4])
        elif len(leaf[count])==4:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1], leaf[count][2],leaf[count][3])
        elif len(leaf[count])==3:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1],     leaf[count][2])
        elif len(leaf[count])==2:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0], leaf[count][1])
        elif len(leaf[count])==1:
            childset_max(count, leaf[count][0])
        count=count+1
    return max


max_move()
leaf=[]
leaf.insert(0,[max[0],max[1],max[2]])
leaf.insert(1,[max[3],max[4],max[5]])
min_move()
print(leaf[0][2])
childset_min(0,leaf[0][0],leaf[0][1],leaf[0][2])
childset_min(1,leaf[1][0],leaf[1][1],leaf[1][2])
leaf=[]
leaf.insert(0,[min[0],min[1]])
childset_max(0,leaf[0][0],leaf[0][1])
print(leaf)
```

Code can be optimized and i am the process of doing so, some prints are just to check some things so dont mind them, but at the min_move call below the leaf.insert, i am getting error list out of range, but when done manually, as seen below the function call, it works just fine, why i am getting the error. The code is actually a minmax algo, just saying

Comment: While you are calling `min_move()`, in `leaf` there are only two elements while you are trying to access upto 6

Comment: yeah, but since it's an if i thought that this part of the process is accessed only at the specific parameter(if len is 6), it doesn't matter?

Comment: The list element accessing part is not inside `if`. So it will be evaluated for every value of `count` i.e. 0 to 6. Which in turn raise the error

Comment: i pretty much understand what you are saying, but is there a way i can fix it without huge alterations?

Comment: list object is not callable is the new error of the day

Comment: Because you used `min` as a variable name. **Do not use keywords as variable name**

Comment: Ok got it, but i still don't know how to fix it. Should i change the min variable at the start?

Comment: Change the variable name from `min` to something else like `minVal` everywhere in your code

Comment: for your list [[1, 8], [5], [6, 4, 7], [9], [3, 2], [6, 10, 2]] as initialized in the above example, can you explain what you're trying to do and the desired output?

Comment: Ok i fully understood what you were saying, code works perfectly now, i did the same to max, thanks a lot, didn't know about the min being a keyword, makes sense though